# Can’t activate Redis Object Cache

Tags: connection

I’m trying to activate the Redis Object Cache plugin on my WP site and keep encountering this error message.

Redis is unreachable: Connection refused [tcp://127.0.0.1:6379]

I contacted my host provider and they said they can’t see any issue on my cPanel so I should seek help elsewhere.  So here I am.

After googling the problem I tried deactivating my Jetpack and WP Protect plugins then reinstalling Redis but to no avail.  The same message appears.

Any advice would be appreciated but be aware I’m not very experienced, sorry.

Thank you. V

I thought deactivating my Firewall would help but it didn’t.